# How to keep showing the dynamic submenu when hovering over parent menu or submenu in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I need help regarding this sidebar in vuejs, I am trying to make a dynamic sidebar where I have to keep open the submenu while hovering over the parent menu or the submenu, whenever I remove the mouse from parent the submenu disappear. I need to keep opening the submenu. Here is my code :

```
<div v-for="item in items" class="categories" >
       <p  @mouseover="onOver(item)" @mouseleave="onLeave">{{item.title}}</p>
       <div v-if="ShowSubMenu" class="subMenu">
           <div v-for="childItem in item.child" > <p class="text"> {{childItem.childTitle}}</p> </div>
           </div>

       </div>

     </div>
```

Vue Js:

```
data: {
  ShowSubMenu: false,

    items: [
    {
       title: 'name'
      },
      {
       title:'hoverMe',
       child : [
       {childTitle : 'ChildTitle1'},
        {childTitle : 'ChildTitle2'},
         {childTitle : 'ChildTitle3'},

       ] ,
       },
       { 
        title: 'name3'}
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    onOver: function(item){
        if (item.child != null) {
      this.ShowSubMenu=true;


      }
    },
    onLeave: function(){

      this.ShowSubMenu=false;



    }
  }
```

css:

```
.categories{
  background-color:red;
  width:100px;
  height:200px;
}
.subMenu{
  background-color:red;



  height:150px;
  width:150px;
  position:absolute;
  top:100px;
  left:150px;

}
.text{
  color:blue;





}
```

Comment: JsFiddle link:https://jsfiddle.net/dc7akrj9/2/

Answer (score 1):

This would be one of the possible solutions to your problem. It's purely CSS based too:

https://jsfiddle.net/vugrjbn6/16/

```
.categories{
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.subMenu{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}

.categories:hover .subMenu {
  display: block;
}
```

It works by displaying the submenu only if the category is hovered. The important thing to realize is that category contains the title AND submenu. So by default submenu is hidden, if you first hover the title it gets displayed, and it stays displayed as long as you keep hovering title or submenu (as both are part of category).

Comment: Thanks mate, but the submenu must show when there is a childmenu. I can't figure that out.

Comment: Wait, can you explain a bit? You want to have it displayed always when there is a submenu ? Can you describe once again how it should behave ? I might have misunderstood :P

Comment: Well, there might not always be a submenu under parent menu. When there is, the sub menu should appear on hover and it should remain open till I am hovering over the parent menu or the submenu. Like 'alixpress.com'.

Comment: Well my example covers everything hover wise. For it to not display submenu if there are no children, simply render submenu conditionally `<div class="subMenu" v-if="item.child">`. I think this answers all your issues perfectly now ;-)